# Question about axiom A4 of abelian category

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an additive category. If one requires only the existence of kernels and cokernels, then for any morphism $\varphi:X\rightarrow Y$, there exist two diagram
\begin{equation}
K\overset{k}{\rightarrow}X\overset{i}{\rightarrow}I,\ I'\overset{j}{\rightarrow}Y\overset{c}{\rightarrow}K'
\end{equation}
with $k=\text{ker}\varphi,i=\text{Coker}k,c=\text{Coker}\varphi,j=\text{ker}c$. Then there is a morphism $l:I\rightarrow I'$ such that $\varphi=j\circ l\circ i$. How to prove $l$ is both a mono and an epi? It's an exercise in Gelfand's book.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I make no progress... In fact, I kind of suspect it's wrong because there is an exercise in Weibel's book with the same conclusion but addionally assuming "every epi is coker of ker, every mono is ker of coker".